# Recording Error when changing camera in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I am new to programming and learning Swift. 
I am creating an app that uses the camera but when I try to switch to the front camera i'm getting an error **Thread 1w: EXC_BREAKPOINT** when I try to record a video.

The error occurs in the func `startRecording()` in the line

```
if (connection?.isVideoOrientationSupported)!{connection?.videoOrientation = currentVideoOrientation()}
```

I kinda stuck with my program with this error. pls help!

```
enum CameraType {
    case front
    case back
}

var camera = CameraType.front

func switchCamera() -> Bool {

    captureSession.stopRunning()
    previewLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

    var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice! = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: .builtInWideAngleCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .front)


    if (camera == CameraType.front) {
        captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: .builtInWideAngleCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .front)
        camera = CameraType.back
    } else {
        captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        camera = CameraType.front
    }

    let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
    if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
        captureSession.addInput(input)
        activeInput = input
    }


    if captureSession.canAddOutput(movieOutput) {
        captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)
    }

    print("Abidi")

    return true

}

func reloadCamera() {

    if switchCamera() {
        setupPreview()
        startSession()
    }

    view.addSubview(dismissButton)
    dismissButton.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 12, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 12, width: 50, height: 50)

    view.addSubview(frontCameraButton)
    frontCameraButton.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 12, paddingLeft: 12, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 35, height: 35)


}

func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    reloadCamera()

}

func startCapture() {

    startRecording()

}


func tempURL() -> URL? {
    let directory = NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString

    if directory != "" {
        let path = directory.appendingPathComponent(NSUUID().uuidString + ".mp4")
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    }

    return nil
}


func startRecording() {

    if movieOutput.isRecording == false {

        let connection = movieOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        if (connection?.isVideoOrientationSupported)! {
            connection?.videoOrientation = currentVideoOrientation()
        }

        if (connection?.isVideoStabilizationSupported)! {
            connection?.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.auto
        }

        let device = activeInput.device
        if (device?.isSmoothAutoFocusSupported)! {
            do {
                try device?.lockForConfiguration()
                device?.isSmoothAutoFocusEnabled = false
                device?.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                print("Error setting configuration: \(error)")
            }

        }

        outputURL = tempURL()
        movieOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: outputURL, recordingDelegate: self)

    }
    else {
        stopRecording()
    }

}

func stopRecording() {

    if movieOutput.isRecording == true {
        movieOutput.stopRecording()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t use force unwrapping. Instead check isVideoOritstionSupported for true:

> connection?.isVideoOrientationSupported == true

Comment: Thanks you very much! My program is now working. I really appreciate it.